# JQuery Plugin with database records- Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have found following JQuery plugin to show the records in alphabetical orders.

http://esteinborn.github.io/jquery-listnav/

I am using demo one. I have implemented in codeigniter and got successful to print all the records. However, all the records appearing only under `"All"` option. It does not display records alphabetically.

I am not sure either am I using this plugin in the correct way ? Following is my code:

```
   <?php if (!$companies): ?>
             <tr>
                    <td colspan="4">No companies in the system yet...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php 
                else :  
                ?> <ul id="demoOne" class="demo">
                    <?php
                            $i = 0;
                            foreach($companies as $company) :
                                ?>

                     <li>
                     <a href="#"> <?php print $company->title; ?></a>
                  </li>
                  </ul>
          </tr>
                    <?php 
                            $i++;
                            endforeach;
                            endif; 
                                ?>
```

Following is script:

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#demoOne').listnav();

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html doesn't seem to be correct. Try:

```
<?php if (!$companies): ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="4">No companies in the system yet...</td>
</tr>
<?php else : ?>
<tr>
    <ul id="demoOne" class="demo">
        <?php
        $i = 0;
        foreach($companies as $company) :
        ?>
        <li>
            <a href="#"> <?php print $company->title; ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php
        $i++;
        endforeach;
        ?>
    </ul>
</tr>
<?php
endif;
?>
```